# Is it possible to script just a part of a table, i.e. to insert are filtered first?

Tags: t-sql

I've been working on my local copy of the database for quite a time now. So, some tables are out of sync with the one we use for development. I'd like to script those rows only so that it can be run there.

When I say generate script, it does it for the whole table. Is there a way to generate a script with condition?

Comment: Backup your table, then delete the rows you dont want scripted. Then script the table again.

Comment: try this: http://www.adeptsql.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a database you're going to continue working with, it will save a lot of pain in the long run to use database change scripts. E.g., http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2008/02/02/versioning-databases-change-scripts.aspx